# Accidentally removed grout behind bathtub caulk, necessary to replace?

Tags: bathtub, grout, caulk

I got so excited my first time removing caulk that I believe I have removed some grout as well that was behind the caulk.

Of course, I'm most worried about water damage, so is it best to replace the grout that was there? Or would caulking over the gap be good enough to keep water out?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Grout's not waterproof anyway, but good caulking is

Answer (score 1):

Grout at that location does not last. I think tilers put it there to get the job "done" with only one session. I would think that a proper job would leave out grout there and just use long lasting caulk.

The best way to proceed would be to remove all the grout and seal with caulk or silicone sealer.

**EDIT**

But if you remove the grout be careful not to damage the finish on that tub.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to reply. I'm just curious, how would using grout there with caulk put on top on the grout be faster than just caulking it? If anything it seems like the way they did it would take longer.

Also, when I'm removing the grout, there is a lot of grout that is far back in the deep recesses of the gap which I cannot reach, with any tool I have currently at least. Does it matter if that grout is still there?

Comment: It does not matter if the grout is there. No need to remove the grout if it doesn't interfere with caulking. Just caulk over it.